# Unable to access other service of docker-compose from HTML

Tags: html, docker, docker-compose

I want to connect two services via docker-compose. One of them is one HTML file being served by Apache, and another is going server, that simply logs the request and return 200, succeed. I don't know what is the correct way of writing an action link in the `<form>` tag.

I've named my images like frontend and server and signed action property as http://server:8080/user/add.

**Here is my form:**

```
<form action="http://server:8080/user/add" method="post">
    Name: <input name="name"><br>
    Sname: <input name="sname"><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: server
  frontend:
    image: frontend
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
```

server works as expected (if run it locally) with
`curl -d "name=name&sname=sname&email=email" -X POST http://localhost:8080/user/add`

But after hitting the button browser redirects me to server:8080 and tells that page is not found.

What is the right way of linking services in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the browser runs on the host machine, the request is sent from the browser and not from the docker container. We can use service name to communicate between containers; but cannot use service name to access container from the host machine (where the browser is running). To access container from host machine, we need to expose the port from `server` service to host machine by adding the required ports to be exposed in `docker-compose.yml` (assuming application is running on port 8080 inside `server` container):

```
  server:
    image: server
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
```

Then, change `server:8080` to `localhost:8081` in the `action` attribute.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8081/user/add" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Now when the browser makes request to `localhost:8081`, the request will be forwarded to `8080` port of `server` container.

**If you don't want to expose the port from `server` container**, you would need to proxy the requests for a certain path from `frontend` container to `server` container using something like [this](https://serverfault.com/a/832206/448479) for Apache server. This way, you can use `/api/user/add` for action attribute (assuming `/api` is the proxied path). Now, the browser will send the request `/api/user/add` to `frontend` container. `frontend` container will see that the URL starts with `/api` and forwards the request to `server` container within the docker network.

Comment: `localhost` stands for container's ip address. I need to post to another container.

Comment: I see.. misread your question. Updated the answer now. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Omg. Provide some theory please. And edit '8080:8081' to '8081:8080', SO doesn't allow me to edit so small piece.

Comment: Already done and moved the description above the code. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm bit tired and didn't catch that it's not what I want. I want make my services communicate via docker network. Not through the port on my machine.

Comment: I'm sure that this answer should have fixed your issue where the borwser says `page is not found`. That said, I'd like to understand your use case clearly.

Comment: `frontend` server serves HTML files (where one of the HTML file has the form). On clicking submit button, you need to send a request to the server container. Now, HTML files are served on the host machine. Host machine does not have a way to communicate with docker container using service name. That's the reason we had to expose the port from server container to host machine, so that the browser can access the container using `localhost:<port>`.

Comment: If you don't want to expose the port from `server` container, you would need to proxy the requests for a certain path from `frontend` container to `server` container using something like [this](https://serverfault.com/a/832206/448479) for Apache server. This way, you can use `/api/user/add` for `action` attribute (assuming `/api` is the proxied path). Here, the browser will send the request `/api/user/add` to `frontend` container. `frontend` container will see that the URL starts with `/api` and forwards the request to `server` container within the docker network.

Comment: I guess this is what you mean by "I want make my services communicate via docker network".

Comment: I've updated the answer with this information. Hope it works for your use case. Cheers!

Comment: Wow, update is great. I'll check this later and mark your answer if everything works. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When you serve html file from your apache running on docker, it will be render on your browser (your host machine). So when you complete the form and post it, the browser will send the data to `http://server:8080/user/add` that is not publicly accesible, and I see that you don't want to expose it directly. If you want to send the data from your `frontend` server, you will need to add some backend functionality to your frontend application that handles the response data that the clients will send (because the browser is which sends the form, not your `frontend`). 
To summarize if you do not expose your `server` to be accesible, you will need to add something else to handle the data that the client sends and then send it to your server.

Comment: For example...? I've kind of come to this already. Can you provide some example of realization for this architecture - when we want to deploy frontend in separate container.

Comment: Sure, take a look into this [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) . In the server side you should add the functionality to send the data to your `server` container.